# Google Merchant payout India

Tags: android-pay

I am a developer from India. I have implemented in-app purchase in my app. But I havent received the payout in my bank account yet. 
As mentioned in this link https://support.google.com/payments/answer/4392008?hl=en&ref_topic=3092361, I am eligible for the payout only if I cross the minimum amount. But there is no minimum amount mentioned for my country. What can I do?

Comment: On that same page you linked to in your question, there is a way for you to contact official Google Support. [Your question is off topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: it seems google-wallet is not launched in india, show how you have integrated ?

Answer (score 0):

Developers based in Argentina, Brazil, India, Russia, Taiwan, Indonesia, Malaysia, Thailand, and the Philippines: Your revenue will be paid out once a month through a wire transfer to your bank account.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2700656?hl=en